# FolderBrowserDialog change language

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, folderbrowserdialog

I have an application where user can choose between 2 languages.

Is to possible to change the FolderBrowserDialog language(Buttons, Browse for folder).
Maybe with CultureInfo?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible: the `FolderBrowserDialog` is a Windows component, so its language only depends on the system language.